# How to launch my app on connecting to USB?

Tags: ios, xcode, usb, external-accessory

I want to enable my app to launch when the USB connects. I imagine there are two approaches to this, the first having some sort of external monitoring process which is always running and checking for such an event, the second would be a process within the app itself.

Having spent the whole day on Google, I first thought I could use the ExternalAccessory.framework to monitor the USB port. However, the only examples I've seen is when the app is already running. Is there any process I can use that will allow me to add my app for launching when the iOS starts syncing?

Alternatively, is it possible to use ExternalAccessory for this purpose and I'm just going about it the wrong way?

Comment: This will not be possible on a non-jailbroken device.

Comment: Thank you for your reply cmyr, I suspected that may be the case due to lack of information available on-line. Could you possible expand on it a little more.

Comment: I actually don't have reference to any specific APIs, I just have a *high degree of confidence* that this functionality isn't possible. For one thing, apple doesn't allow you to run a daemon or to run in the background (except in certain special cases). Ultimately though, this just runs counter to Apple's general design philosophy. Apps to not get to "decide what the user wants", and there's no way for the system to know that the user wants your app to launch in every instance that a USB connection is made.

Comment: Thank you cmyr, your logic makes sense, I guess I'll have to find an alternative

Comment: If it's a custom USB device respecting MFi, in fact you may be able to do that. For example, I worked on a iOS app with a small bluetooth toy device. When connected to it, the app will launch (sometimes with showing a pop-up asking if we want to launch the app). Well, at least for a bluetooth ExternalAccessory, and the manufacturer part is unknown for me.

Comment: Thank You, MFI seems the best route as I'm sure we can set the USB as a custom USB device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the comments above, the comments by cmyr are indeed correct and as correctly pointed out by Larme, the only solution is to use MFi which can configure the USB device as a custom setting which will always prompt the iOS as a connection.